# Android Studio - how to edit this font colors in build.gradle

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, build.gradle, android-studio-2.1

I has installed vim dark custom theme and edited to fit my needs, but i realized some problem in `build.gradle`:

[image]

As you can see, the boolean value of `multiDexEnabled true`, `incremental true`, and `preDexLibraries = false` is dark blue which hard to recognize.

I also has problem to shows this `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'`:
[image]

Anothe example is android -> sourceSets -> defaultConfig's `minSdkVersion` and `multiDexEnabled`:

[image]

So my question is, how to edit this two font colors(dark blue and underline) of `build.gradle` in Android Studio 2.1.2 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like the syntax highlighting for Groovy (which is the language used for Gradle) is not completely adjusted for the dark background:

You can change this in *File > Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Groovy*.

There you can check which parts of code have the wrong color setting. Especially look out for properties that do not *Use inherited attributes*; tick that checkbox to inherit the settings from Java. In your case it might be the *"Unresolved reference access"* and *"Keyword"*:

[image: Groovy language syntax highlighting settings Android Studio]